# BasicPlayer: absolute path mp3 InputStream does not work?

Tags: java

My problem is that I am using the BasicPlayer library javaZoom to play audio files. I can play without problems files, but since the call is to "File", if the call is to "InputStream" does not work and I have no idea why. I googled for all Internet corner and I saw nothing. Can anyone help me?

My code :

```
/**
 * Entry point.
 * 
 * @param args
 *            filename to play.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BasicPlayerTest test = new BasicPlayerTest();
    // test.play("src/musica/demo.mp3");

    try {

        // get mp3 path
        String mp3 = "musica/demo.mp3";
        InputStream in = BasicPlayerTest.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(mp3);
        test.play(in);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR!" + e,
                "Simple Player Java", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Error: EOFException

Comment: If you are using getResourceAsStream(mp3) the Resource must be on classpath. Otherwise it doesn't work

Comment: Yes. It is. But don´t work!

Comment: in my project I have a folder called musica within that folder I have my mp3 songs for example demo.mp3 so <code>// get mp3 path
        String mp3 = "musica/demo.mp3"<code>;

Comment: Have you tried building a .jar and running that?

Comment: No. I haven't. Thanks a lot for all.

Comment: jl1.0.1.jar, mp3sp.1.9.5.jar, basicplayer3.0.jar, tritonus_share.jar, commons-logging-api.jar in my CLASSPATH.

Comment: So there is no folder musica in your classpath?

Comment: Of course there is. But take look at the error: javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream

Comment: BasicPlayer don´t work with InputStream path just work File path!!! Or I´m gonna crazy.... Error: java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)

Comment: I´ve got it! // get mp3 path
player.open(getClass().getResource("musica/vocal.mp3"));